# how to explain a block of code of friend

Tags: javascript

I recently had a 3rd party write a registration code generator for a new abandoned piece of software (well a family of products to be more accurate) and they coded the whole thing in HTML/JavaScript.  I understand the HTML side of the page that makes all the visual elements work; what I'd like to know is what all the JS does behind the scenes so I can better explain it to my friend who was curious about it.  Can anyone break down the following code to basic statements that I can explain to my friend?  I really don't know anything JS so this will give me a little bit more information.

```
function generate() {
var vc = 178890;
var edition = [
    [223987, 543238],
    [998732, 215588],
    [776490, 366591]
];
var module = [
    [322547, 226789],
    [632788, 129874],
    [399872, 112256],
    [200876, 679032],
    [666634, 188897],
    [877334, 766952],
    [222990, 777778],
    [229347, 543832]
];
var i;
var sum = 0;
var name = $('#name').val();
var addr = $('#address').val();
for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    sum += name.charCodeAt(i);
}
for (i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {
    sum += addr.charCodeAt(i);
}
var s = 12*(sum + Math.floor(sum*67/12472));
if ($('#product').val() === 'avs') {
    s += 886;
} else {
    s += 288;
    if ($('#timed').prop('checked')) {
        reg = moment($('#regdate').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        exp = moment($('#expdate').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        var date_re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
        var valid = true;
        $('#invalidreg').html(reg.creationData().input.search(date_re) >= 0 && reg.isValid() ? '' : (valid = false, ' invalid date'));
        if (exp.creationData().input.search(date_re) >= 0 && exp.isValid()) {
            if (reg.isSameOrAfter(exp)) {
                $('#invalidexp').html('expiration date should be after registration date');
                valid = false;
            }
            else {
                $('#invalidexp').html('');
            }
        } else {
            $('#invalidexp').html('invalid date');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!valid) {
            clear();
            return;
        }
        var epoch = moment('1800-12-28');
        s += 3*exp.diff(epoch, 'days') - 2*reg.diff(epoch, 'days') - 34;
    }
}
$('#serialnum').html(67*sum);
$('#versioncode').html(vc + s);
var row = $('#edition tr:nth-child(1)');
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(edition[i][0] + s);
    row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html(edition[i][1] + s);
    row = row.next();
}
row = $('#modules tr:nth-child(1)');
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    row.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(module[i][0] + s);
    row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html(module[i][1] + s);
    row = row.next();
}
```

note: the 3rd party developer who coded this said when asked for "design-time notes to further document the processes used" he "did not have any such notes"

Comment: I feel sorry for whoever wrote that code, and even more sorry for anyone who has to maintain it. It's a mess. Explaining it properly would take longer than rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one ugly child of a scripting monster. The expletive per minute rate just rose exponentially.

```
function generate() {

    // Random (arrays of) magic numbers (probably the key to the universe)

    var vc = 178890;
    var edition = [
        [223987, 543238],
        [998732, 215588],
        [776490, 366591]
    ];
    var module = [
        [322547, 226789],
        [632788, 129874],
        [399872, 112256],
        [200876, 679032],
        [666634, 188897],
        [877334, 766952],
        [222990, 777778],
        [229347, 543832]
    ];

    // Retrieving the values of Name & Address form inputs as "name" and "addr" with an 
    // external library called jQuery

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var addr = $('#address').val();


    // Beginning of a block to calculate "sum" (set sum to zero) - the next couple of lines
    // seem straightforward, I just have no idea what objective these incantations have. 

    var i;
    var sum = 0;

    // Iterate over all the letters in the "name", retrieve the letter's 
    // character code and increase sum by the value of that character code

    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        sum += name.charCodeAt(i);
    }   

    // Iterate over all the letters in the "addr", retrieve the letter's 
    // character code and increase sum by the value of that character code

    for (i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {
        sum += addr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // Do some more magic number cacluations with sum, to retrieve a value "s"

    var s = 12*(sum + Math.floor(sum*67/12472));

    // If the value of the "product" input is avs, increase the value of s by magic number 886

    if ($('#product').val() === 'avs') {
        s += 886;
    } else {

    // Otherwise, increase it by 288

        s += 288;

    // If the "timed" checkbox has been selected ... 

        if ($('#timed').prop('checked')) {

    // Use the external library "moment" to normalize the input data from "regdate" and "expdate" fields

            reg = moment($('#regdate').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
            exp = moment($('#expdate').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');

    // As we don't trust the "moment" date validation, we#re also going to use a regex to check the 
    // validity of "regdate"

    // The regex checks if the date is formatted with slashes, such as: 23/12/2004

            var date_re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

    // Somewhere in the murky depths further down there's probably a global check, if the input data
    // is valid, so we need a global flag for it. 

            var valid = true;

    // Now we apply the regex we defined earlier and use moment's own "isValid" method to check if the
    // "reg" date is actually valid. 

    // If it's not, we inject an error message into the HTML element "invalidreg" and set the global
    // valid flag to false

    // If "reg" is a valid date, nothing happens. 

        $('#invalidreg').html(reg.creationData().input.search(date_re) >= 0 && reg.isValid() ? '' : (valid = false, ' invalid date'));

    // Now we also validate the "exp" date in the same manner ...

        if (exp.creationData().input.search(date_re) >= 0 && exp.isValid()) {

    //  ... but we also check, if it is the same as the "reg" date. If they are the same, we output
    // an error message into the "invalidexp" HTML element and set the "valid" flag to false

    // If they are not the same, we reset the contents of that HTML element. 

            if (reg.isSameOrAfter(exp)) {
                $('#invalidexp').html('expiration date should be after registration date');
                valid = false;
            } else {
                $('#invalidexp').html('');
            }

    // If "exp" is not valid we display an error message in the "invalidexp" HTML 
    // element (and set the valid flag to false)

        } else {
            $('#invalidexp').html('invalid date');
            valid = false;
        }

    // If the global flag is false (ie "exp" or "reg" date are invalid or the same) ..

        if (!valid) {

    // Call a "clear" method (not defined in this fragment of code) and cease further processing 
    // by calling a return

            clear();
            return;
        }

    // If everything is valid (*yay*) - define a new magic date on the 28/12/1800 
    // (who know's why this particular date)

        var epoch = moment('1800-12-28');

    // And we're back to magic number caclulations on the value of "s"
    // where we are adding 3 times the difference between the magic epoch date and the "exp" date
    // and then subtracting 2 times the difference between the epoch and the "reg" date. 
    // Oh, and subtractign 34 ... the *bleeep* knows why. 

        s += 3*exp.diff(epoch, 'days') - 2*reg.diff(epoch, 'days') - 34;
    }
}

// We now wet an HMTL element "serialnum" to the 67 times the value of "sum" 
// (which we calculated earlier)

$('#serialnum').html(67*sum);

// The version code is the value of vc (you can find it right at the top of this script ... it's 178890)
// plus the value of s. We display this value in an HTML element "versioncode"

$('#versioncode').html(vc + s);

// We now grab a new variable and set it to the first row in an HTML table element. 

var row = $('#edition tr:nth-child(1)');

// For the first three rows of the table (starting with the row we just defined), we set the values of 
// the 2nd and 3rd table cells to a random number calculation of "s" and "edition" 
// (edition is defined right at the top of the script)

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(edition[i][0] + s);
    row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html(edition[i][1] + s);
    row = row.next();
}

// Same thing for a different table, and with the "module" magic number. 

row = $('#modules tr:nth-child(1)');
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    row.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(module[i][0] + s);
    row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html(module[i][1] + s);
    row = row.next();
}
```